How to find a good WiFi router setup for my situation
Hoping this is the right place for this type of query, and if there is another Stack Exchange site that would be better, please tell me what it is.
I am a retired software engineer, more on the coding side than on the networking side. Unix and Linux don't scare me, and in fact my daily computing needs are handled on a Ubuntu system.  I live in a house in Arizona with good view of the skies and I'd like to pursue an astronomy hobby, using open source tools wherever possible.  Keeping my head in the software game is of almost equal importance to the astronomy.
What is hanging me up now is my WiFi router system.  I have a Google Nest WiFi with one additional connection "point".  My intention was to place the additional point near a window from which it would be a short jump (30 feet) out to my telescope and the Raspberry Pi that controls my astronomical equipment.  Alas, I learn today that my "point" which the Google Home app says has "excellent" connectivity to my router, is not picked as the point of connection by my outdoor Raspberry Pi, which instead insists on connecting to my main router with which it has a very weak connection.  Trips to the Google Help site, basically blame this on "poorly designed" WiFi clients on devices for which it disclaims any responsibility, offering the user no way to configure the system to their liking.
More generally, I find the Google Home smartphone app to be overly concerned with user-friendliness, at the expense of reducing the functionality available to the administrator of the home network.  Basically, how to connect doorbells, speakers, etc.  It's not just Google, this is the trend in the industry.  I don't mean this as an attack on Google. Control via a smartphone app seems to be the standard in modern equipment.
I am starting to look for a different router setup, one that would allow my outdoor equipment to make a wifi connection to a strategically placed secondary WiFi extension that would allow me to build the kind of home network I am desiring with enough control to insure that the desired WiFi connection point is communicated with without losing any of the functionality for indoor computers, smartphones, TVs, etc. A real router web page, not just an app, would be a nice plus.
Does such a system exist? I don't even know the keywords by which I might search for such a beast. How would I go about looking for what I am after?
UPDATE: To the anonymous know-it-alls who downrated this question:
Please know that I spent several hours researching this topic.  As I said above "I don't even know the keywords by which I might search for such a beast."  If you, or anyone else DOES know how I might go about researching such a thing, why not leave me a comment?  I have described my situation.  Please tell me where I can find the answer to my question or the name of the thing I ought to be looking for.

tldr: You just need a reasonably boring router that supports AP mode (for wired connections) or a mesh setup, rather than a mesh kit. Prosumer brands might also be an option.
I'm not really going to recommend a specific product - but rather suggest a set of technologies, and how to use them. Basically Mesh routers. while pushed pretty hard by a lot of ISPs and consumer hardware providers are not great unless you absolutely can't get wired backhaul, and are not really that technical.
A few brands support their regular routers doing mesh (TP-link and their sub brands support easymesh, and Asus supports AIMesh), but what you really need is a decent router acting as a router, and having APs or routers running in AP mode. Often each router has its own webUI but its not that bad to manage. I run 2 APs independantly connected to a single 'wired only' router at my parents place for coverage.
'Better' consumer routers support multiple SSIDs  - running your RPi on a seperate SSID would solve the 'connecting to the wrong AP' problem. Since each AP's seperate - you might also be able to just set up a second SSID or a guest network on the desired AP.
You might want to look at higher end prosumer brands, which either have management software or a web based controller you run yourself if you want a step up or more visibility. You'd want to stick to one brand - say unifi or microtik and its controller, and specifics aren't really on topic for us there, but they do nice things like co-ordinate handovers between APs and do signal maps set up correctly

thanks. "prosumer" - a new word to me. Multiple SSID's.  Sounds like something to look for.  And "management software" - Man do I hate smartphone-app-only setups.

Here is a link to what eventually solved the problem for me.  Although WiFi chips in devices are supposed to be able to find the best access point to a network they are trying to connect to, this doesn't always work.
Here is the solution I found in my case on the Pi5. It worked like a charm.
